# Stop Spark from serializing null fields when writing to Cosmos

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb

I have a spark notebook that overwrites documents in Cosmos. Some of these documents have null fields which are not serialized when they are saved to Cosmos, while others do have data for those fields. When I write the dataframe back to Cosmos, I end up with documents that have a null field.

Is there a way to not serialize this column for rows for which that value is null?

Example

Document as it exists in Cosmos:

```
{
    "id": "7b354753-e817-41f5-848d-780dab44d179",
    "pk": "20763ae4-8394-467d-ba3c-5ab363c40f90",
    "documentType": "ExampleDocument",        
    "userId": "20763ae4-8394-467d-ba3c-5ab363c40f90",
    "label": "Needs to be updated"
}
```

Document after being overwritten:

```
{
    "id": "7b354753-e817-41f5-848d-780dab44d179",
    "pk": "20763ae4-8394-467d-ba3c-5ab363c40f90",
    "documentType": "ExampleDocument",        
    "userId": "20763ae4-8394-467d-ba3c-5ab363c40f90",
    "label": "Updated With Spark",                
    "details": null    
}
```

I still want `details` field to be serialized, but only for documents where it is not null.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this configuration when writing to the cosmos db: `"spark.cosmos.serialization.inclusionMode" -> "NonNull"` following this link: [cosmos spark configuration](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3_2-12/docs/configuration-reference.md)

See sample below:

```
val someDF = {dataFrameToWriteInComosDB}
val CosmosDbContainerConfig = Map(
  "spark.cosmos.accountendpoint" -> {yourCosmosDbEndpoint},
  "spark.cosmos.accountkey" -> {yourMasterKey},
  "spark.cosmos.database" -> {yourDatabase},
  "spark.cosmos.container" -> {yourContainer},
  "spark.cosmos.serialization.inclusionMode" -> "NonNull",
  "spark.cosmos.write.strategy" -> "ItemOverwrite"
) ++ StandardThroughputControlConfig

someDF.write.format("cosmos.oltp").options(CosmosDbContainerConfig).mode("append").save()
```